# Change all request if contains a word

Tags: .htaccess

I want to change all request uri in my project if the request contains phrase "ajax". For example now I have:

`http://www.address.com/ajax/getIdeas`

And when the user changes language it adds `/ru/` in the URL. So the link became `http://www.address.com/ru/ajax/getIdeas` and its not working. All I want to do, is to change via .htaccess all links which contains word `ajax` and `ru`. So if the request is `http://www.address.com/ru/ajax/getIdeas` it should redirect to `http://www.address.com/ajax/getIdeas`. How to do it?

Comment: If the chosen language does not alter what the ajax-request should do, why don't you just fix the script that does this ajax request to point to `/ajax/getIdeas` instead of `ajax/getIdeas`?

Comment: yes, I did this, but I'm looking for better option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this rule in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file to remove 2 digit language rom start of your URLs:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^[a-z]{2}/(ajax/.*) /$1 [L,NC,R=301]
```

Comment: its looks nice, but I need to delete "ru" for all `/ajax/` calls

Comment: If it worked out, you may mark the answer as accepted by clicking on tick mark on top-left of my answer.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend against making rules to rewrite, or redirect, your ajax requests. Redirects will cause your POST ajax requests to stop working. Your rewrites in general will cause extra, unnecessary work to occur regardless.

In your case I would recommend fixing your scripts to not use language-specific ajax-requests where they do not cause different results. You would use an url relative to your root (`/ajax/page`) instead of relative to your current url (`ajax/page`).

Comment: hey, after some test according answer below using .htaccess I decided to redirect all language requests to non-language request of my ajax callback. It works much faster :)